# Can we play .swf files in iPhone using Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, adobe, flash

Can we programmatically play,export .swf files in the ipad using Objective-C, if then could any one suggest the native or external library which supports this feature.

Comment: Apple iPhone does not still support Flash and more than 2 million developers are waiting for this to become true.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2TBlbXb2sM.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the iPhone SDK and iOS doesn't support Flash ([well known fact](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2008/11/adobe-flash-on/) :). There're [several apps](http://www.alwaysontechnologies.com/cloudbrowse/) that convert Flash / Shockwave Flash Files to HTML(5) on the server side.

Stating the Apples Terms

> An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code
>   by any  means, including without limitation through the use of a
>   plug-in architecture, calling other  frameworks, other APIs or
>   otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded and used in  an
>   Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple's
>   Published APIs and builtin interpreter(s).

Comment: if i want to locally run the .swf then what?

Comment: Can we convert any file to .swf files programatically in objective C using any native or external framework

Answer (score 1):

Audio Playback and Recording Formats
The audio playback formats supported in  OS are the following:

```
*AAC
*HE-AAC
*AMR (Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech)
*ALAC ( Lossless)
*iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
*IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
*linear PCM (uncompressed)
*µ-law and a-law
*MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3
```

The audio recording formats supported in  OS are the following:

```
*AAC (on supported devices only)
*ALAC ( Lossless)
*iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, for speech)
*IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
*linear PCM
*µ-law and a-law
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html