# How to play the flash file on ios5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we play .swf files in iphone using Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677718/can-we-play-swf-files-in-iphone-using-objective-c)

I want to implement the splash screen on my app. I have an "SWF" file. How to implement the  splash screen using this file? Please tell me. Any 3rd party sdk or any framework or library for the same? please give me any idea for this functionality.

Comment: **NOT** possible. Any trivial google search for "iphone flash" would reveal this.

Comment: To run natively:Using adobe air sdk you could create standalone flash app that runs on iOs

Answer (score 4):

`Swf` is not supported by `iOS`. You can take the image sequence and use it in place of a swf file.

Comment: "You can take the image sequence and use it in place of a swf file." - it's against Apple guidelines to add something splash screen like thing after the real splash screen and most likely will be rejected. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that because:

- iPhone does not support SWF. This was one of the biggest fight in the mobile industry between Adobe and Apple
- the splash screen is shown by the OS while your application is starting and not by user code
- any additional animation after splash screen is against Apple's guidelines and will be rejected. See also [Adding animation between splashScreen And home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992200/adding-animation-between-splashscreen-and-home-screen)